# How to prevent the last box in a column from being editable JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a JavaFX TableView that I succeeded in making one of the columns editable using this:

```
colUnitPrice.setOnEditCommit(event -> 
    event.getTableView() 
         .getItems()
         .get(event.getTablePosition().getRow())
         .setUnitPrice(event.getNewValue())
);
```

The problem is I do not want the very last one to be editable as it contains a Label. Is there a way of preventing this?

Comment: Try setting the [editable property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#editableProperty) of the non-editable label cell to false.

Comment: Aside: not related to question, but can you just use [`event.getRowValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.CellEditEvent.html#getRowValue--) rather than `event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow())`?